# Memory requirements for PHP + MySQL on Windows platform

Tags: windows, php5, mysql5

I have cloud server at RackSpace that has 2GB of memory. OS is Windows Server 2008 R2 x64. As of now server is pretty fast. I plan to configure IIS and install SQL Server Express 2008 R2 x64, so memory is somewhat at a premium. There will be no users on the server to generate real load, I got it for educational purposes.

I also would like to install PHP and MySQL to familiarize myself with this technology. However, I have no idea about how much memory they require to work (I don't care if they are slow) and if it will bring server to a crawl.

Can anyone give any feedback if what I want to do is viable on 2GB of RAM?

Comment: Is 2GB even enough to run Windows?

Comment: If he is using Windows Server Core, yes.

Comment: Yes, 2GB seems to be sufficient for Windows itself. After boot 1.5-1.2 GB is available (I have not installed SQL Server yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not care about performance, then as long as you have enough swap space you will be able to run them.

For low workload you can configure mysql and apache in 256 MB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Running stock installs with no custom code, all four entities should happily eat a large part of your memory doing nothing. PHP doesn't really count since it's invoked by IIS, but MySQL and MSSQL will both eat a noticeable chunk of RAM just by being installed and running.

When you cross into "too much" depends entirely on what you do with all four after that. A memory leak in an IIS App Pool can cause just as much grief as overly large database tables in either database.